# Issues with figuring out Django ORM, what would be the correct way to query an inner join?

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

This is my first time using Django, so far I am impressed I love the way the framework just works. I am currently working on my first application and am dealing with Database stuff however, I am having issues figuring out how to do an inner join without running a raw query.

So I have this model:

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True) 
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=17, null=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=250)
    tokens = models.IntegerField(null=False, default=0)
    server = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, default="Hub")
    lastseen = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, null=False, default="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")


    def __str__(self):
        return 'id: %s, uuid: %s, username: %s, rank: %s, balance: %s, tokens: %s, server: %s, lastseen: %s' % (self.id, self.uuid, self.username, self.rank, self.balance, self.tokens, self.server, self.lastseen)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'player_data'
```

This model grabs the basic information about the player, but then I also need to grab information about the player to see if they have been banned before, and the way I usually do this with raw is a join on UUID here is the second model.

```
class Bans(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    uuid = models.ManyToManyField(User, db_column="uuid")
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'banned_players'
```

Now all I really need to do is make it so the two UUIDs are linked across tables, I have tried all of the different Django methods and am having trouble, what would be best to do here? And would it be a better idea to rename the models after the actual tables themselves?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are still using the relational database mindset to design django, I don't think django works this way. You should not use `uuid` to link two models unless you really need to. You should only have:

```
class Ban(models.Model):
    # id is not redundant, django would define it for you
    # id = models.IntegerField(null=False, primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Then you do `user_obj.ban_set.all()` to get all bans for a user.

The `_set` is how you visit reverse forignkey fields in django, take a look at the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#related-objects).

By the way, model names should be in single form not plural form, django would add plural form for you when necessary.

Comment: When running "user.ban_set.all()" in the python shell,
it returns ForeignRelatedObjectsDescriptor object has no attribute all.
I just need to be able to reference the UUID in the ban model with UUID in the user model

Comment: `user` is an object not `User` model.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it is easier to use MySQLdb for joins. Django ORM is not made for complex joins.

To install MySQLdb:

```
$ gunzip MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf MySQL-python-1.2.2.tar
$ cd MySQL-python-1.2.2
$ python setup.py build
$ python setup.py install
```

To do read operations:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import MySQLdb

# Open database connection
db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","testuser","test123","TESTDB" )

# prepare a cursor object using cursor() method
cursor = db.cursor()

# Prepare SQL query to INSERT a record into the database.
sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE \
       WHERE INCOME > '%d'" % (1000)
try:
   # Execute the SQL command
   cursor.execute(sql)
   # Fetch all the rows in a list of lists.
   results = cursor.fetchall()
   for row in results:
      fname = row[0]
      lname = row[1]
      age = row[2]
      sex = row[3]
      income = row[4]
      # Now print fetched result
      print "fname=%s,lname=%s,age=%d,sex=%s,income=%d" % \
             (fname, lname, age, sex, income )
except:
   print "Error: unable to fecth data"

# disconnect from server
db.close()
```